# Changing code to remove 2 records for the first line

Tags: php

The code below grabs the first two records and displays them on the first line.
All the other records are displayed after that but three per line.

Each record has these four fields: name, information, picture and position.

Can someone please help me remove the bits of code that removes the first functionality...??
I do not need the first two records displayed in the first line but need them all to be three per line, starting from the first record.

```
        $members = get_field('team_members');
    foreach($members as $k => $member) {
        $class = "span".($k < 2 ? 6 : 12/(count($members)-2));
        $pic = $member['profile_picture'];
        if (!empty($pic)) {
            $url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($pic, 'squares');
            $pic = '<img src="'.$url[0].'" width="'.$url[1].'" height="'.$url[2].'" alt="'.$member['name'].'" />';
        }
        else $pic = '';
        echo ($k === 2 ? '<div class="clearboth"></div>' : ''),
            '<div class="'.$class.'">',$pic,'<h4>' , $member['name'] , '</h4><p><span class="focus">',
            $member['position'] , '</span>', $member['information'],
            '</p></div>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I got it to where I wanted it:

Change `$class = "span".($k < 2 ? 6 : 12/(count($members)-2));`
to
`$class = "span".($k < 0 ? 6 : 12/(count($members)-2));`
and remove this section completely:
`($k === 2 ? '<div class="clearboth"></div>' : ''),`

I am sure there are other (better?) ways of getting to the same result but this is the way I did it.